# Identity function in Dart?

Tags: dart

Does Dart have an identity function?  I understand that I can just write, `(x) => x`, but it would seem to be slightly easier to understand code if there was something like `Function.identity`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in the core libraries (but possibly in some third-party package).  It's trivial to make your own generic function:

```
T identity<T>(T x) => x;
```